# Maximizing the utility of performing PCA

Tags: pca, data-visualization

Besides for generating a biplot and screeplot, are there any other useful graphical outputs that I can obtain from running PCA on a multivariate dataset?

So, to sum up, my question really comes down to how much juice I can squeeze out of performing PCA on any arbitrary multivariate dataset, or complementing the PCA with a follow-on test (e.g., linear discriminant analysis or factor analysis) to glean as much useful information (both graphical and numerical) as possible from a dataset.

Comment: "the coefficients of the variables in the linear combination of PC1 (and PC2) can only be obtained by running linear discriminant analysis" -- I don't understand what that means. PCA gives you the coefficients directly, LDA has nothing to do with it. There is no way you could run LDA to get anything like that.

Comment: PCA and discriminant analysis work with the eigenvectors of different matrices, what makes you think that the coefficients are the same?

Comment: @amoeba I see, this must mean that I can get coefficients directly from my loadings.  I've edited my question.

Comment: @JohnK Can you please elaborate this point a little bit for me, maybe with a relevant link?

Comment: Well, you use the eigenvectors of the covariance or the correlation matrix for PCA but for discriminant analysis you use the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{W}^{-1} \mathbf{B}$, where the first matrix is the "within" variance and the second the "between". These two are not the same, unless I am missing something of course.